# Terminal command to open Safari

Tags: java, macos, command-line, terminal

Is there a way to open a new Safari tab with a given URL using a terminal command?
I'm only interested for it to work on OSX at this point.

I want to use that command to open a new tab from a java application.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If Safari is your default browser, you just use

```
open <url>
```

for example:

```
open http://www.google.com
```

You can also use this command to open any file with its registered application.

Comment: mixing your solution with that of Moritz, if Safari is not your default browser use `open -a Safari <url>`

Comment: This _sort_ of works. However it will also launch the default browser at the same time at least on Ventura. I have not yet found a solution that ONLY launches Safari when Safari is not configured as the default browser.

Answer (score 10):

There are several ways to do this. The simplest way would be to use `/usr/bin/open`:

```
/usr/bin/open http://stackoverflow.com/
```

will open the URL in the standard browser or

```
/usr/bin/open -a Safari http://stackoverflow.com/
```

will explicitly use Safari.

You can also use AppleScript via the `javax.script` API (JSR 223) but I do not know the syntax right now.

Comment: Could you tell me the difference between /user/bin/ open and the way @bunting suggested ?

Comment: `/usr/bin/open` is just the full path. You will need the full path if you use e.g. `ProcessBuilder` to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `open` command on MacOS. (see `man open` for more information about this command).

In your case you can write something like that: `open -a Safari https://www.stackoverflow.com` and it works. (NB: Remember to specify the protocol!)

In addition, I wrote an useful script to interact with Safari from MacOS and one of the options of this script is exactly what you want, see it on GitHub here https://github.com/antoniolanza1996/openSafariFromTerminal

Comment: Thats exactly the same as existing answer? :)